# Curl 2-Legged Token with Autodesk Forge fails (AUTH-008)

Tags: curl, autodesk, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to get a 2-legged token like it shows here: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/

This is what I enter in cygwin (that id and secret are the ones from the example, but I use my own id and secret):

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d ' client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE& client_secret=eUruM8HRyc7BAQ1e& grant_type=client_credentials& scope=data:read'
```

But I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 10:06:09 GMT
* Server Apigee Router is not blacklisted
< Server: Apigee Router
< Content-Length: 231
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x600057550; line 1965 (connection #0)
* multi_done
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
{"developerMessage":"The required parameter(s) client_id,client_secret,grant_type not present in the request","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-008","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-008"}
```

How is it even possible that there's a missing parameter from an example I took from the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every experienced programmer knows full well that there is no limit whatsoever to the number of ways mistakes can occur.

In this case, I see a space in your data, before you specify the scope.

Could that be the reason?

There is another leading space in front of the client id.

Maybe that one is ignored.

Here is a working sample of exactly what you are attempting to achieve:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/10/forge-intro-formats-webinars-and-fusion-360-client-api.html#3

Comment: It works, looks like I had more spaces there. I didn't know it's so white space sensitive. Why they don't use trim or tokenize by spaces?